# Unable to switch on Install via USB on Redmi Note 4

Tags: android, android-studio, usb

MI Note 4

```
Android version: 7.0

MIUI Version: 9.0
```

I'm unable to switch on Install via `USB` option for `debugging` purpose. I have tried switching to mobile data and using MI account . Also, tried turning off `MIUI` optimization. Nothing worked till now.

I always get the error that says **"The device is temporarily restricted"**

I'm stuck for 2 days now.

Could anyone here help in resolving this?

> > Note: It was working fine till I updated the device to Nougat. Kindly help if you're using **Nougat** along with **MIUI 9.0**

Edit: Using **VPN** helped.

Comment: developer options are enabled? and usb debugging?

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020237/install-app-via-usb-the-device-is-temporarily-restricted

Comment: Yes, Developer mode and USB debugging are enabled

Comment: the Wi-Fi has to be turned off and then the installation over USB works as expected.

Comment: @Dileep Patel, I have tried everything mentioned in the link provided. Nothing worked till now.

Comment: Wifi is turned off.. Im using mobile data

Comment: @AkashRaj   you need to turn off **Instant Run** in android studio

Comment: @Akash Raj . Please check this. There was bug in instant run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340314/android-studio-2-1-1-running-old-apk-file

Answer (score 2):

Try this to turn off **Instant Run**

Unlock your phone and go to main Settings on your **Xiaomi Redmi** devices

Scroll down to find **About Device** and tap on it.

Locate **MIUI Version** and tap several times on it.

you will get a message **`"You're now a developer!"`** on your device screen.

Go back to main Settings.

Run **Additional Settings**, and tap Developer options to enable it from there.

Scroll down to find **USB Debugging** option and enable it.

If you need to turn off **Instant Run** in android studio , go to

**File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.**

Answer (score 0):

@Akash Raj
If below link is not working

1- [Install app via usb: The device is temporarily restricted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020237/install-app-via-usb-the-device-is-temporarily-restricted)

2- http://en.miui.com/thread-544718-1-1.html

Then try to this way because it's working for me.

Connect your Redimi mobile with device hence come to display many option like below image

[image]

Select **Transfer file** now it's working.